# how to record video (1080p 30fps) from raspberry pi camera Using Gstreamer?

Tags: raspberry-pi, gstreamer, h.264

I am a beginner in Gstreamer.

My objective is to record a video at 1080p resolution at 30 fps in H264 format from my Raspberry pi camera using Gstreamer following pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v  v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! capsfilter 
caps="video/x-raw, width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1" ! videoflip 
method=rotate-180 ! gst-debug ! videoconvert ! videorate ! x264enc! avimux 
! filesink location=test_video.h264
```

After I ran the above pipeline,
I did not get any kind of error and recorded video shows 1080p and 30fps but frames are dropping heavily.

Is this right pipelining or not?

Am I missing any elements in this pipeline?

Comment: `x264enc` is a software video encoder. The raspberry pi is not poerwful anything to make enough useful with it. You will need to capture in H.264 from the camera directly.

Comment: Burn baby burn… you are going to put your PI in flames.

Comment: If you are using webcam like logitech c920 you can encode wideo on camera getting 1920x1080@30 but not flip...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x264enc` is a software encoder and uses a lot of CPU power. Raspberry pi has an OpenMax hardware h264 encoder which can be accessed with gstreamers `gst-omx` bindings. You can use the hardware encoder with inserting an `omxh264enc` element instead of `x264enc` element.

Comment: After lots of changes i used this pipeline but still frame missing issue is there.  ``gst-launch-1.0  --gst-debug-level=3   -v   v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! capsfilter caps="video/x-raw, width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1" ! queue ! videoflip method=rotate-180 ! videoconvert ! videorate ! queue ! omxh264enc ! queue ! avimux ! filesink location = test_video.h264 ``


          CPU USAGE :  htop :: 33% (high resolution)
           MEMORY USAGE :: 2.4% (124 mb)

Comment: http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/Video-Recording-issue-in-Gstreamer-td4690453.html#a4690493